# Amazon Rekognition API - S3 MetaData Issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

I am trying to detect faces in an image using AWS Image Rekognition API. But getting the following Error:

Error1:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectFaces operation: Unable to get image metadata from S3.  Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
```

Python Code1:

```
def detect_faces(object_name="path/to/image/001.jpg"):
    client = get_aws_client('rekognition')

    response = client.detect_faces(
        Image={
            # 'Bytes': source_bytes,
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': "bucket-name",
                'Name': object_name,
                'Version': 'string'
            }
        },
        Attributes=[
            'ALL',
        ]
    )

    return response
```

The Object "path/to/image/001.jpg" exists in the AWS S3 Bucket "bucket-name". And the region Name is also correct.

The Permissions for this object '001.jpg' is: Everyone is granted Open/Download/view Permission.
MetaData for the Object: Content-Type: image/jpeg

Not sure how to debug this. Any Suggestion to resolve this please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be asking the service to fetch the object with a version id of `string`.

> **Version**
>
> If the bucket is versioning enabled, you can specify the object version.
>
> Type: String
>
> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 1024.
>
> Required: No
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_S3Object.html#rekognition-Type-S3Object-Version

Remove `'Version': 'string'` from your request parameters, unless you really intend to fetch a specific version of the object from a versioned bucket, in which case, provide the actual version id of the object in question.

Comment: Having the exact same error message but without including the version parameter in the request. Any other ideas what the issue could be? Using boto3. Bucket is public, and I even made a new IAM user with full s3 and full rekognition access.

Comment: @Sam, it's tricky to speculate, but ensure that you aren't passing an object version, and that `Name` doesn't have a leading slash.  Enable logging on the bucket and see if you can spot the request that Rekognition is making.  Also, CloudTrail's logs of API requests might reveal something of value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and avoid using '-' or whitespaces in  bucket and uploaded file names solved it for me.

Maybe removing underscores can also help.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, new solution:
I got the same error message.
My mistake was due to a region mismatch; My S3 bucket was residing in us-east-2, but my recognition client defaulted to us-west-1.
I changed the line

```
client = get_aws_client('rekognition')
```

to

```
client = get_aws_client('rekognition', region_name='us-east-2')
```

and it worked.